# Google Maps InfoWindow Trigger - Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a working google map using the JavaScript API v3, but I am getting a javascript error on a new function I added.

I'm working on a new function to make links outside the map that show the respective infowindow on its marker. It should [work like this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map2.html).

I have the new features commented in my code on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jefe317/XCP2P/4/) as `// TESTING`

In the console, clicking the links outside of the map throws the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: htmlinfowindowclick is not defined
```

Here's my code:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jefe317/XCP2P/4/)**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `htmlinfowindowclick` function should be outside of the `initialize` function. Also `var gmarkers = [];` should be defined outside your functions so that it can be accessed by both functions.

```
var gmarkers = [];

function htmlinfowindowclick(item) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[item], 'click');
}

function initialize() {
    [...]
}
```